# Workbox build not generating service worker

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, service-worker, workbox

I am trying to integrate workbox-build into my grunt build system for pre-caching of files.
I am following this article - [generateSW Mode](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-build)

After following the above google documentation i have made a function definition as

```js
var workBox = require('workbox-build');

function swCache(){
    workBox.generateSW({
        swPath : path.join('target/app', 'sw_cache.js')
    })
    .then(function(details){
        console.log(details);
    })
}
```

The above swPath is a relative path to my grunt file.
Below i am attaching the code for implementing  grunt task of the above function

```js
grunt.task.registerTask('generateSWCache', function(){
        swCache();
    });

    if (env === 'production') {
        build = preBuild.concat(productionBuild).concat('generateSWCache');
    } else {
        build = preBuild.concat(developmentBuild).concat('generateSWCache');
    }
```

The task generateSWCache is running but it is not producing any sw_cache.js for pre-caching of files.
Below is a screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

generateSWCache is an async task, so you should use Grunt's this.async function.

```javascript
var workBox = require('workbox-build');

function swCache(done) {
    workBox.generateSW({
        swPath : path.join('target/app', 'sw_cache.js')
    })
    .then(function(details){
        console.log(details);
        done(true);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        done(false);
    });
}

grunt.task.registerTask('generateSWCache', function(){
    swCache(this.async());
});

if (env === 'production') {
    build = preBuild.concat(productionBuild).concat('generateSWCache');
} else {
    build = preBuild.concat(developmentBuild).concat('generateSWCache');
}
```